# Cartoon from 70s to 90s about a bald man trying to steal a little girl's short golden hair

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking for a cartoon. It was probably from the 80's but I watched it on TV around 2002-3. It was about a little girl with short golden hair, that I think lived in some sort of magical forest with her mushroom friends. Those mushroom friends were protecting her against a bald man who was always trying to steal her hair so that he could wear it. He always pictured himself in the mirror with her hair, but always failed to steal it from her.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details? For example, you say 70s-90s but that's a large window, could you narrow it down some? Also where did you see this?

Comment: So, *probably* not the Smurfs, which was my instinctive reaction. Technically, Smurfette is both little, and a girl. There are even mushrooms involved, which as I recall the Smurf's house resembled.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone has been looking for this cartoon it is called: "The Tale of The Three Bears"

You can find it on YouTube:

From a capsule description on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00008K7A5): "Little golden-haired Vicky and The Three Bears become great friends and have many adventures together, including an escape from the castle of the evil Dr. Egghead."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This looks like a good find!  I've added a bit of description to your answer; you want to be as clear as possible about how the answer matches the question.  Check out [answer] and take the [tour].